# Converting function to upload File to upload Uint8List

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the following function to upload a file from my app to a server:

```
void _upload(File file) {

    if (file == null) return;
    setState(() {
      _textoInfo = "subiendofotoalservidor".tr();
    });

    String base64Image = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
    String fileName = file.path.split("/").last;

    http.post(Uri.parse(phpEndPoint), body: {
      "image": base64Image,
      "name": fileName,
    }).then((res) async {
      print("respuesta servidor ${res.body}");

      setState(() {
        _textoInfo = "fotoperfilactualizada".tr();
        miImagen = fileName;
      });


      print("foto subida ${miImagen}");

      _cambiarFotoAdmin(miImagen, widget.administrador.email, context);




    //  cambiarImagenUsuario(fileName);
    }).catchError((err) {

    });

    http.post(Uri.parse(phpEndPointFoto), body: {
      "foto":fileName,
      "id": miId,
    }).then((res) async {





    //  cambiarImagenUsuario(fileName);
    Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context, listen: false).cambiarImagenAdministrador(fileName);
    }).catchError((err) {

    });


  }
```

Now in my new app, I am executing my flutter project on the web browser, and the image_picker is not picking an image from the device gallery but on the computer file system, and the picked image is from type Uin8List.

How should I change the function _upload(File file) to _upload(Uin8List file) ?

EDIT

Here you have the function used to select the image:

```
  Future<void> _openImagePickerGallery() async {

    if(!kIsWeb){
      final XFile? pickedImage =
      await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = File(pickedImage.path);
        });
      }
    }
    else if(kIsWeb){
      final XFile? pickedImage =
      await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage != null) {

        var f = await pickedImage.readAsBytes();
        
        
        setState(() {
          hayFoto = true;
          webImage = f;
        });

        //  _image = File(pickedImage.path);

      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Your existing function already operates on a `Uint8List` once it calls `File.readAsBytesSync`.  Refactor your code from that point and allow the caller to specify the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Friend I hope you do well,

```
void _upload(Uint8List fileBytes, String fileName) {

  if (fileBytes == null) return;

  setState(() {
    _textoInfo = "subiendofotoalservidor".tr();
  });

  String base64Image = base64Encode(fileBytes);

  http.post(Uri.parse(phpEndPoint), body: {
    "image": base64Image,
    "name": fileName,
  }).then((res) async {
    print("respuesta servidor ${res.body}");

    setState(() {
      _textoInfo = "fotoperfilactualizada".tr();
      miImagen = fileName;
    });

    print("foto subida ${miImagen}");

    _cambiarFotoAdmin(miImagen, widget.administrador.email, context);

    //  cambiarImagenUsuario(fileName);
  }).catchError((err) {

  });

  http.post(Uri.parse(phpEndPointFoto), body: {
    "foto":fileName,
    "id": miId,
  }).then((res) async {

    Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context, listen: false).cambiarImagenAdministrador(fileName);
  }).catchError((err) {

  });
}
```

for getting filename and pass it to _upload method :

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

Future<void> pickAndUploadFile() async {
  FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
  if (result != null && result.files.single != null) {
    String fileName = result.files.single.name;
    Uint8List fileBytes = result.files.single.bytes;
    _upload(fileBytes, fileName);
  }
}
```

you need to adjust to read the file and it's name.

let me know that I could help you.

happy coding...

Comment: Nice, thank you, and how can I get the filename from the  Uint8List file?

Comment: dear mvasco I have edited the answer, please let me know that i could help you.

Comment: There is no need to retrieve any filename. It is working fine as it is. I can give the Uint8List file the filename I want. Thank you

Comment: your welcome bro, Pass auf dich auf or Fatti cura 